# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My first project on ruby on rails. I get this error [image]

My print.html.erb is a static page.It has a link `<a href="posts/index">Show</a>`

And the print page is the index page in my case i.e localhost:3000 opens the print page.

This is my index.html.erb page(this is the linked page)

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td><%= post.text %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

This is my controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

 def new
  end

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def print
end

end
```

This is my routes file

```
Watermark::Application.routes.draw do
resources :posts
  root "posts#print"

  post 'posts/index' => 'posts#index'
  post ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

I guess the problem is in the routes file.

Comment: HTTP Verb like `get`, `post` declaration should come before `resouce :post` and `resouce :post` will handle all `CURD` opeations no need for declaring it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes contain some bogus additions. You shouldn't have added

```
post 'posts/index' => 'posts#index'
```

That's only going to conflict with existing routes. You should remove it.

`resources :posts` is all you need to generate the [seven default RESTful routes in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), including `index`, which should simply by at `/posts`, not `/posts/index`.

You should also remove the two catch-all routes, they're not useful anymore. It seems likely that you're working from a pretty dated tutorial.

Comment: it worked...could u tell me putting `/posts/index`why does it go to show action?

Comment: Because you're using `resources :posts`, which defines a `GET /posts/:id` route, which is higher in the routing file than your custom route. You're typing `posts/index` into the address bar with issues a GET request. It matches `/posts/:id`, with an id of "index". If you were issuing a POST request, it would match your custom `post 'posts/index'` route.

Comment: The two catch-all routes are `post ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'`. They're not needed any more, their use is discouraged.

Comment: thnx for the explaination.wats d alternative to the 2 catch-all routes?i guess match is the keyword i need to use